# Keyboard shortcuts for Red Gate SQL Compare

Tags: sql-server-2008, redgate, sqlcompare

In Red gate SQL compare
Are there any keyboard shortcuts to move from the pane in which we have to tick, to the pane in which the actual difference is shown so that I can scroll down to look at the difference.

Like if the difference is readily visible then I just mark the change with a space and then move to the next with a down key. But if the changes in the lower pane are hidden and have to be scrolled then is there a way to do it using keyboard only?

Answer (score 0):

The version I'm using (10.3.1.140) has keyboard shortcuts for setting the diff preview's height.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> sets the preview to the largest size.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> collapses the preview.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> sets the preview to half-height.

What I usually do is keep the preview pane collapsed, and then (if I care to check the difference) hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to see as much of the script as possible, then collapse the preview down again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.